# Require.js: In require.config how to load js specific to IE?

Tags: requirejs, html5shiv

I am new to require.js. I am using html5shiv for IE polyfill, which execute only in IE.

Now, how to define IE specific condition in require.config ?

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery',
    html5shiv : 'libs/html5shiv'
  }
});
```

html5shiv should get loaded only in IE

Comment: why don't you use IE specific conditional statements <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="libs/html5shiv-3.6.2.js"></script> <![endif]-->

Comment: @MaheshSapkal that's what we are using before require.js. Question is how to do the same in require.congif() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

late to the party perhaps, but you can use [bowser](https://github.com/ded/bowser) its already amd-ready

```
require(['bowser'],function(bowser){
    if (bowser.msie && bowser.version < 9) {
        //include your html5shiv/shim/modernizr here
    }
});
```

best of luck!

Comment: Thanks jessie for your note !

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5shiv code needs to happen in the `<head>` and if you use some other means to load `html5shiv.js` its built in shim code won't get called in time.

Comment: true, in this case you would want to put your script tag (with the data-main attribute) in the head instead of before the closing body tag like many people do to avoid the need for `$(document).ready()` calls (which is entirely unnecessary with requireJS anyhow!).